# Representing the number 500 as a byte

Tags: c#, byte

I was given a code base that I do not want to make a whole lot of changes. I was told to change this variable MAXSTEPS from 200 to 500. What I didn't know was that MAXSTEPS was a byte variable, so I can't just say MAXSTEPS = 500. Is there anyway I can do this without removing it from the enum?

```
public enum SeqOverLoad : byte 
{
    DONT_BYPASS = 0,
    BYPASS = 1,
    MAXSTEPS = 200
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `SeqOverLoad` needs to be a `short` or `int` now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The value type (byte, short, int, etc) specifies the size in memory that the value will take up. Each of these values must be stored in the memory as binary data (only 0 and 1).

A byte is 8 bits, which means it can store anything from `0000 0000` to `1111 1111` in binary. Unsurprisingly, `1111 1111` is 255 in base 10, so that's the maximum value you can store there.

Other data types take up more memory bits, so have the capacity to store higher values.

Comment: Within SeqOverLoad, can I turn MAXSTEPS into a byte array? something like MAXSTEPS [] = {250, 250} and then convert that to an int later on?

Comment: Why don't you just use an `int`?